# UnReferences the dlls on closing Winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, vba, dll

I have .NET Form in which multiple of user controls being used and inside the user controls multiple of dlls are referenced. The application is a combination of vba and .NET forms and we open up the .NET form from VBA through COM interfacing.

The issue is that when I close the form, it does not unrelease / unreferenced the dlls used inside the form because of that it it keeps on increasing the size of the `MSACCESS.exe` process whenever I open up the form again. I tried to call `GC.Collect` and `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()` but it did not resolve the issue.

How can I unreference those dlls during closing of the form?

Comment: This might be alittle off. but have you tried looking at the OnFormClosed function of the form?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onformclosed(v=vs.110).aspx

You should be able to handle killing stuff onclose there

Comment: Unreference the dll's or objects within the dlls?

Comment: In your MSAccess code, are you `Set myNetCOMForm = Nothing` when you are done with it?

Comment: Pretty sure `GC.Collect` won't have any effect if your .NET COM-visible code still has a dangling COM reference to it

Comment: Yes, I did the form = nothing on exiting of the function. I also override the Dispose method on all of the controls being used

Answer (score 1):

> How can I unreference those dlls during closing of the form?

You can not unload an assembly which is loaded into a .NET `AppDomain`, but it is also only loaded once -> no increase in memory here when "reloading a form".

I guess you have some memory-leak inside your code: Have you tried pinning it down using a memory profiler?

Comment: _"You can not unload an assembly which is loaded into a .NET AppDomain."_ - I may be trolling but that is incorrect.  [If you want to unload some assemblies but not others, consider creating a new application domain, executing the code inside that domain, and then unloading that application domain.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173101.aspx)

Comment: @MickyDuncan: My statement is correct: You can unload an `AppDomain`, but NOT only one assembly inside that domain without unloading the complete domain -> you can not unload an assembly only an `AppDomain`. But of course you are right with "create a seperate `AppDomain` for assemblies if you need to unload them"...

Comment: I guess it can be read two ways. We appear to agree anyway my friend.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds more like you're creating unmanaged objects and not releasing them when the form closes.

If this is the case then you need to keep track of the unmanaged objects and release them within OnFormClosed.

Comment: How can I unrelease the unmanaged object on the form closing.

Comment: That depends on how you're creating them. I'd need to see code to determine that.